# Javascript executes more than once inside jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-dialog

i'm trying to use javascript code inside "jquery dialog" and my code executes more than once.

Simple example..

```
<div id='dialog'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('inside'); 
        }); 
    </script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Dialog init');
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    })
</script>
```

And my output is:

1. inside
2. Dialog init
3. inside

Comment: Sorry, bad formatting. fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that makes sense then...

jQuery probably locates the contents of `#dialog` to somewhere and the code inside gets executed again.

Why is there JS in the `#dialog` box? Is it loaded with XHR? If not: move it to where the rest of the domready code is.

Do you want an event to trigger when the dialog is shown? Is that why there is code in the dialog? If so, there is en event API for that: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#events

Comment: Thanks... I will use your advise and will move code from the dialog. I thought maybe it was dummy mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe this is what you want, cmiiw please :)

```
<div id='dialog'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Dialog init');
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    })

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      open: function() {
                 console.log('inside');
            }
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: No, i need to call "console.log('inside')" when the page is just loaded. I need to get some extra data from server and initialize some js controls inside... and i need to do this before user will see this dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
<div id='dialog'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        console.log('Dialog init');
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            open: function() {
                console.log('inside');
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Using the open event causes your code to run when the dialog is open and not when the document is ready.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open